# LINQ variable cast AsEnumerator, yet the view throws error saying its a System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this in a method:

```
        var Student = _db.Students.Join(_db.StudentGrades, s => s.ENumber,
           sg => sg.StudentENumber, (s, sg) => new { Student = s, StudentGrade = sg })
           .Where(sc => sc.StudentGrade.LetterGrade == "A").Select(sgl => new SCourse
           {
               LastName = sgl.Student.LastName,
               CourseCode = sgl.StudentGrade.CourseCode,
               CourseNumber = sgl.StudentGrade.CourseNumber
           });
        return View(Student.AsEnumerable());
    }
```

When I go to view the expected results in the view, I get an error saying it is being sent to the view as a Query, not as an enumerable.

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of 
type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Practice.ViewModels.SCourse]', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of 
type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Practice.ViewModels.AllStudents]'.
```

Why would it try and say that it is receiving a query item instead of an enumerable?

Here is the beginning of the View if this might have something to do with it:

```
@model IEnumerable<Practice.ViewModels.AllStudents>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
 @model IEnumerable<Practice.ViewModels.SCourse>
```

instead of

```
 @model IEnumerable<Practice.ViewModels.AllStudents>
```

you passed a model named **SCourse**. But in view file you want model **AllStudents** thats why you are getting this error.

Comment: I feel very dumb.  Thank you.